# The Lateral branch on a Red Clapp's Pear 3 tier espalier tree broke at the graft. How can I replace it?

Tags: fruit-trees, grafting, espalier

[image][image: Graft view]I reconnected and taped the original branch back in place but it eventually died.
There is a healthy matching branch on the other side of the trunk.
Can I cut it in 1/2 and graft the cutting onto the now empty side, or will cutting the still healthy branch in 1/2 ruin it? Any thoughts/ suggestions?

Thank

Scott

Comment: a picture or two would help, the graft area, the branch you could graft

Comment: This is a dwarf. The healthy branch is currently 5 feet long, this is the 1st growing season.